# gnome-terminal default zoom level

Tags: terminal, fonts, gnome

I've just updated to Ubuntu 20.04, and I can't setup my terminal font to my desired size without anti-aliasing, at normal zoom level. I dislike the fuzziness.

This is with font Terminus at 10 (it's actually crisp, imgur seems to make it fuzzy). Too large:
[image: Terminus 10, zoom 1]

If I choose Terminus at 8, the font gets fuzzy:
[image: Terminus 8, zoom 1]

If I go back to Terminus 10, but zoom out with Ctrl+-, it looks like I want (and as it used to in 18.04) (it is actually crisp):
[image]

Starting `gnome-terminal` with `--zoom=0.85` yields the result I want.

How do I include the zoom level to the profile in use, or at least to the default value when starting a new terminal?

(any other solution for the actual problem I'm trying to solve is also welcome).

EDIT: I have `gconf-editor` from way back, but it seems obsolete. Not all gnome-terminal profiles show up in `/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles`.

Answer (score 8):

hey dude not the same method but the road leads to rome (i think)

1. Open you're terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)
2. Right click your teminal window and select preferences
3. Select the unamed profile at the bottom of screen
4. Under the "Text" tab, click "custom font", make sure the box is ticked
5. Adjust the size of the font to what you want

If you have a look at the tabs in this "general" area you will see you can also adjust the window size (default open size). It is done by adjusting "New tab position" from 'next or what eva it says, to "Last". Provided you make a change: resize and move the window, the next time you open the terminal it will open in the same location and size.

Comment: This should be the answer